# Как вывести строку таблицы sqlite3 PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite3

Искал, пишут, что как бэ нельзя без бубна. Это ведь самое важное, тупо показать статью. Если нет изкоробки такой возможности, на кой чёрт тогда это ПДО вообще?

Вот это выводит все строки:

```
<?php

    $db = new PDO('sqlite:data.db'); 
    $st = $db->query('SELECT * FROM articles');
    $results = $st->fetchAll();

?>

<?php foreach ($results as $row): ?>
    <p>ID: <?= $row['id'] ?></p>
    <p>Date: <?= $row['date'] ?></p>
    <p>Title: <?= $row['title'] ?></p>
    <p>Text: <?= $row['text'] ?></p>
    <br />
<?php endforeach ?>
```

А надобно, чтобы по http://site.org/?id=1 выводилась строка с id = 1

Как это можно реализовать стремясь к минимализму кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:data.db');
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id');
    $sth->execute([
        'id' => $_GET['id'] // Это следовало бы проверить перед тем как скармливать базе
    ]);
    $results = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Какой бубен? Разве в sqlite не работает WHERE?
http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php - это на покурить, очень внимательно

Comment: Вот спасибо! А я подобным образом пробовал, но только без проверки :)

Comment: проверки тут и нет. Только подготовленный запрос. в текущем варианте если кто-то зайдет по ссылке example.com/?id=ololo у тебя уйдет запрос в базу с попыткой найти id = ololo. По этому перед тем как делать запрос надо еще проверить число ли пришло

Comment: Ой, не то написал) Я имел ввиду, что execute(); был без парметров. А как сделать проверку?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-int.php

Comment: Вот класс! Спасибо ещё раз!

Comment: Это если id из гет параметров не строкой приходит, я чет запамятовал этот момент. Но на этот вопрос тебе гугл точно ответит быстро

Comment: *разумеется*, "это" приходит строкой.